# How to store and retrieve the date using shared preferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-edittext

[image: a simple task remainder layout]

A simple task remainder application.
I have to save and retrieve the three edit text values in this app using shared preferences.

Which storage option is best for this app,
1.shared preferences
2.internal storage

Comment: Shared preferences is better option instead of internal storage.you can learn more about SharedPreferences here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: @AndRaGhu If my answer is helping you then please accept it.

Comment: In my account there is no feedback?

Answer (score 1):

Storing

```
EditText Task = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ettask);
EditText date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etdate);
EditText time = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ettime);

String taskstr = Task.getText().toString();
String datestr= date .getText().toString();
String timestr= time .getText().toString();

SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor edit = preferences.edit();
edit.putString("pref_task", taskstr); 
edit.putString("pref_date", datestr);
edit.putString("pref_date", timestr); 
edit.commit();
```

Retrieving

```
 pref_task =  preferences.getString("pref_task", "n/a");
 pref_date =  preferences.getString("pref_date","n/a");
 pref_time =  preferences.getString("pref_date","n/a");
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete example:

```
package com.example.logindemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class LoginPage extends Activity {

    EditText name = null, pwd = null;
    SharedPreferences login_pref = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_page);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_edt);
        pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pwd_edt);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_login_page, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void loginMethod(View v) {
        login_pref = this.getSharedPreferences("login_pref",
                MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor login_pref_editor = login_pref.edit();
        login_pref_editor.putString("Name", name.getText().toString());

        login_pref_editor.commit();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, WelcomeScreen.class));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. I feel Shared preference will be a better way

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to Store data into SharedPreferences.

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
editor.putString("Date", mEdttxtDate.getText().toString()); 
editor.commit();
```

For Retrive data from SharedPreferences.

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String mDate =  myPrefs.getString("Date","nothing");
```

it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

for inserting

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

Editor edit = preferences.edit();
edit.putString("pref_empId", _empid);
edit.putString("pref_userType", _usertype);
edit.commit();
```

for getting shared preferences

```
pref_empId =  preferences.getString("pref_empId","n/a");
pref_userType =  preferences.getString("pref_userType","n/a");
```